# Not all items are drawing when using "Parallel.For"

Tags: multithreading, c#-4.0, mono, monodevelop

I am building an desktop application which prints a series of rectangles on the drawing area.
This application is built using MONO C#.

I have no problems using normal "FOR" loop, I am getting the results as expected.

Flowing is the output when i use normal FOR loop

[image]

Flowing is the output when i use normal Parallel.For loop

[image]

As we can see some of the rectangles are missing in between.

I am using ConcurrentQueue to hold the rectangles that are created and pass the same Queue to other function to print it on the drawing area.

following is the code.

```
 public static void DrwaWall (DrawingArea drawArea, string compLevel)
    {
        house.Rectangle rect = new house.Rectangle ();
        house.DrawHouse DrawHouse = new house.DrawHouse ();
        ConcurrentQueue<house.Rectangle> WallHouseQ = new ConcurrentQueue<house.Rectangle> ();
        PointD p1, p2, p3, p4;
        p1 = new PointD (55, 250);
        p2 = new PointD (65, 250);
        p3 = new PointD (65, 90);
        p4 = new PointD (55, 90);
        rect = new house.Rectangle (p1, p2, p3, p4);
        WallHouseQ.Enqueue (rect);
        Parallel.For (0, 27, (i) => {
            p1.X += 10;
            p2.X += 10;
            p3.X += 10;
            p4.X += 10;
            rect = new house.Rectangle (p1, p2, p3, p4);
            Helper.wastetime (compLevel);
            WallHouseQ.Enqueue (rect);
            Gtk.Application.Invoke (delegate {
                if (drawArea == null)
                    return;
                Cairo.Context ct = Gdk.CairoHelper.Create (drawArea.GdkWindow);
                DrawHouse = new house.DrawHouse (ct, WallHouseQ);
                DrawHouse.DrawRectangles ("Wall");
                ((IDisposable)ct.Target).Dispose ();
                ((IDisposable)ct).Dispose ();
                }
            );
            }
        );
    }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your `p1`/`p2`/`p3`/`p4` variables aren't thread safe, so you're likely drawing over the top of existing rectangles.

Instead of incrementing each time, you could compute the appropriate location based on the current index.  For example:

```
Parallel.For(0, 27, i =>
{
    // Make new points...
    PointD p1New = new PointD(55 + (i+1)*10, 250);
    //...

    // Make sure you don't share variables here, either - ie: make a new rect from the new points
    house.Rectangle rectNew = new house.Rectangle (p1New, p2New, p3New, p4New);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I understood what you are trying to say in the first part. i did not understand the second part of it. can you please elaborate or do the modification to the the above code? thanks again for the quick reply.

Comment: @Veeresh Edited - make sense now?